# How to automatically load a module in AngularJS without specifying it as a dependancy

Tags: angularjs, angular-mock

ngMock does some magic to automatically include itself if you include angular-mocks.js in your index.html.

What's the simplest way to force angular to load a module in test mode simply by including a file and not having to edit any module dependencies.

Comment: You cannot do it. There is no way to automate module loading because you must specify the dependencies tree. Angular-mocks is only dependent on `ng` module.

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't true, angular-mocks.js achieves this with ngMock by unshifting ngMock and ng modules into the module array. Their implementation doesn't look very clean to me though (there's a lot of supporting code for that process), I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically include itself" ? **[ngMocks](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular-mocks.js)** uses `angular.module('ngMock', ['ng'])...` to load itself.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to load a module is by calling `angular.module(...)`. **[ngMocks](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular-mocks.js)** loads "itself" by calling:

```
angular.module('ngMock', ['ng']).provider(...).config(...);
```

You don't need to declare a module as a dependency to load it. You can just include `angular.module('<moduleName>', [<moduleDependencies>...]);` in its script.

---

If you mean "how is `ngMock` automagically added to the dependency list of any module loaded using `window.module` or `angular.mock.module`, it is because `ngMocks` creates a custom injector, such that it takes the list of dependencies and prepends `'ngMock'`:

```
window.inject = angular.mock.inject = function() {
  ...
  return isSpecRunning() ? workFn() : workFn;
  ...
  function workFn() {
    var modules = currentSpec.$modules || [];

    modules.unshift('ngMock');   // <-- this line does the trick
    modules.unshift('ng');
    ...
```

---

You could create your own function that prepends your module in the list of dependencies before instantiating, but I hardly believe this will help in testing. On the contrary, it will be one more source of errors (and will result in possibly "hiding" dependency errors).

Comment: it's the second part that I'm interested in - I wonder if there's an elegant way to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Why do you want to make your tests les riliable and error-prone just to save a few keypresses ?