# angularjs [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string in console error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have having error when I try to mock backend with ngmockE2E.

"angularjs [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string"

When I remove ngMock service, it works fine.

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="userApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>IT Beams Angular App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="logo col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
                <h1>logo</h1>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li><a ui-sref="home" class="btn btn-success" ui-sref-active="btn-warning">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="login" class="btn btn-success" ui-sref-active="btn-warning">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="register" class="btn btn-success" ui-sref-active="btn-warning">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="text-area col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
                <h2>Test</h2>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div ui-view></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="text-center">Copyright IT Beams 2015</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(ng){
var userApp =   ng.module("userApp", ["ui.router", "ngResource", "ngMockE2E", "ngCookies", "mainCtrl"]);
userApp.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$provide", function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( "/" );
    $provide.decorator("$httpBackend", ng.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
    $stateProvider
        .state("login", {
            url         :   "/login",
            templateUrl :   "views/login.html",
            controller  :   "loginCtrl"
        })
        .state("register", {
            url         :   "/register",
            templateUrl :   "views/register.html",
            controller  :   "registerCtrl"
        })
        .state("home", {
            url         :   "/",
            templateUrl :   "views/home.html",
            controller  :   "homeCtrl"
        })
}]);

userApp.run("$httpBackend", function($httpBackend){
    var users = [
        { "id"  :   "1", "username" :   "user1@test.com", "password"    :   "user1" },
        { "id"  :   "2", "username" :   "user2@test.com", "password"    :   "user2" },
        { "id"  :   "3", "username" :   "user3@test.com", "password"    :   "user3" },
        { "id"  :   "4", "username" :   "user4@test.com", "password"    :   "user4" }
    ];
    $httpBackend.whenGET("/login").respond(users);

    console.log(testing);
}); 
})(angular);
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278514/how-to-automatically-load-a-module-in-angularjs-without-specifying-it-as-a-depen. It might clear some of your doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run` block is set up incorrectly.

You are passing a string as the first argument instead of a function:

```
userApp.run("$httpBackend", function($httpBackend) {
  ...
});
```

Hence the error.

It should either be:

```
userApp.run(function($httpBackend) {
  ...
});
```

Or if using the inline array notation like you have with the `config` block:

```
userApp.run(["$httpBackend", function($httpBackend) {
  ...
}]);
```

Comment: previous error is gone and now I have "Unexpected request: GET views/login.html" error. Need further help :) thanks

Comment: You're welcome :) I will take a look at it. It's recommended to post a new question describing what you are trying to achieve and the current problem. This way others get a chance to help as well.